# javascript append html to appended before

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append HTML that appended before. Like first Append the key, then append another one to that key.

My goal is to create nested DOM.

Here is the sample,

```js
let result = [  
   {  
      "name":"Component Murah",
      "slug":"components-component-murah-34",
      "id":34,
      "parent":1
   },
   {  
      "name":"Gadget Case",
      "slug":"components-component-murah-gadget-case-35",
      "id":35,
      "parent":34
   },
   {  
      "name":"Components",
      "slug":"components-1",
      "id":1,
      "parent":false
   },
];

$.each(result, function(i, field) {
  if (field['parent'] == false){
    $(`ul[class=nav-categories]`).append(
        `<li class='child-${field['id']}'>
          <a href='/shop/category/${field['slug']}'>
            <span>${field['name']}</span>
          </a>
        </li>`);

  }

  $.each(result, function(i, field){
    if (field['parent'] != false){
      $(`li[class=child-${field['parent']}]`).append(
        `<li class='child-${field['id']}'>
          <a href='/shop/category/${field['slug']}'>
            <span>${field['name']}</span>
          </a>
        </li>`);

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav-categories">

</ul>
```

First one works as well, the second one that finds parent is not working?...

Thank you!

Comment: Using `\`` isn't just a fancy 2019 alternative for quotes, it has a purpose. It allows you to insert variables into text *without* adding everything together. I'll also recommend using jQuery's `addClass()`, `attr()` `text()` etc. instead, which will produce much cleaner code.

Comment: Can you provide an example from the data returned from the api?
Possibility exists that "if (field['parent'] != false)" goes wrong due to falsy data

Comment: @Keyboardninja post edited.

Comment: Edited your question and it works for me!

Comment: My take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nc0kyLro/

Comment: @ChrisG that what i need, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to close the first $.each....Check this sample

```
 var res = [  
   {  
      "name":"Component Murah",
      "slug":"components-component-murah-34",
      "id":34,
      "parent":1
   },
   {  
      "name":"Gadget Case",
      "slug":"components-component-murah-gadget-case-35",
      "id":35,
      "parent":34
   },
   {  
      "name":"Components",
      "slug":"components-1",
      "id":1,
      "parent":false
   },
]

$.each(res, function(i, field){
   if (field['parent'] == false){
       $(`ul[class=nav-categories]`).append(
           `<li class='child-` + field['id'] + `'>
               <a href='/shop/category/` + field['slug'] + `'>
                   <span>` + field['name'] + `</span>
               </a>
           </li>`);           
    }
});  
$.each(res, function(i, field){
   if (field['parent'] != false){
       $(`li[class=child-` + field['parent'] + `]`).append(
           `<li class='child-` + field['id'] + `'>
               <a href='/shop/category/` + field['slug'] + `'>
                   <span>` + field['name'] + `</span>
               </a>
           </li>`);

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample. It has some improvements over your code (Like correct usage of back ticks)

```js
let result = [  
   {  
      "name":"Component Murah",
      "slug":"components-component-murah-34",
      "id":34,
      "parent":1
   },
   {  
      "name":"Gadget Case",
      "slug":"components-component-murah-gadget-case-35",
      "id":35,
      "parent":34
   },
   {  
      "name":"Components",
      "slug":"components-1",
      "id":1,
      "parent":false
   },
];

$.each(result, function(i, field) {
  if (field['parent'] == false){
    $(`ul[class=nav-categories]`).append(
        `<li class='child-${field['id']}'>
          <a href='/shop/category/${field['slug']}'>
            <span>${field['name']}</span>
          </a>
        </li>`);

  }
});

$.each(result, function(i, field){
  if (field['parent'] != false){
    $(`li[class=child-${field['parent']}]`).append(
      `<li class='child-${field['id']}'>
        <a href='/shop/category/${field['slug']}'>
          <span>${field['name']}</span>
        </a>
      </li>`);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav-categories">

</ul>
```

Comment: You're appending all children to the main `<ul>`; 34 needs to be appended to 1 though, and 35 needs to be appended to 34.

Comment: @ChrisG That's actually not the case. If you don't believe me use the inspector tool and see it yourself. <li> just has no default indention that's why it is all on one level.

Comment: True, which means you forgot to wrap child li's in their own ul (this was a mistake in the original code already, but an answer should fix this)

Comment: @ChrisG Depends on how you see it. The author never specified that he wants the second level options intended. An answer is not there to fix things that the author might want, an answer is an explanation to an asked question.

Comment: 1. The indentation is primarily a matter of overriding the default styling of a `<ul>`. 2. Your answer creates invalid HTML. 3. The goal of this website isn't to help individuals with their coding problems but to create a repository of questions and answers which help other users, too. Not fixing what is clearly a simple oversight on the OP's part seems weird in that context.

Comment: @ChrisG 1. As said the author does not want an answer for indentation, but for how to create nested DOM with the JSON provided. 2. If you talk about the `li > li` thing -> yes that's true, but not relevant to the question. 3. The goal is exactly what you said. Everyone who will stumble across this thread will get an answer to the question on how to create nested DOMs with the JSON structure provided (to be fair that might be a relatively small userbase). I am thankful for all your concerns with my answer, but due to missing relevance, I will stop answering now. Have a good day!